# VOX circuit false triggers when touched

Tags: audio

I built a VOX circuit (Voice Operated Switch) which is an audio activated relay that activates when sound is applied from a USB sound card on my computer.

I am having a problem with the switch, however, every time I touch the input line, the switch activates, even with the largest resistor I could use before the switch was not detecting the audio input from my computer.

[image]

R1, R2  10K 1/4 W Resistor
R3  1K 1/4 W Resistor
R4  33K 1/4 W Resistor
C1  1uF Electrolytic Capacitor
Q1, Q2, Q3  2N2222 NPN Transistor
D1, D2, D3  1N4148 Diode
K1  9V Relay

I decided to add an isolation transformer as well as DC removing capacitors in line with the input, and I still had the strange effect, even when touching my aluminum computer, which is isolated from ground.

What are the next steps to eliminate this interference? [Here](https://youtu.be/hnDTmpbI-Bk) is a link to a video I posted showing the issue.

Comment: Did you try using lower-value resistors?

Comment: Yes. Lower value resistors made the device always enabled even when there was no audio nor me touching the circuit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, what happens is that: 1) The mac has ~60v on the aluminum parts (laptop PSUs have caps between mains and laptop ground) 2) Even if it is powered from batteries it has noise on it's case. 3) You act as an antenna, the open, unshunted input as a receiving antenna.

Put 10k across the Q1 (and perhaps 100k across Q4) base and emitter.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an input DC cap is a good practice, you don't know "a priori" what is the DC level of the signal.
Also, the base of Q1 is floating, put a resistor between the base of Q1 and ground (10kohm for example).